# Why is this query slow, it seems simple

Tags: mysql, index, varchar

I have a very typical table of user information for my application, with an average set of columns (ints, varchars, etc).

In this table are two varchar(100) fields:  emailAddress and emailAddress2.

I'm extremely perplexed at why one of my queries is so slow (5+ seconds) and in testing some alternates they are so fast (<= 0.02 seconds).

This query is fast (matching on emailAddress field):

```
SELECT u.userId
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.isActive=1
AND u.emailAddress = 'user@domain.com'
```

This query is also fast (matching on emailAddress2 field):

```
SELECT u.userId
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.isActive=1
AND u.emailAddress2 = 'user@domain.com'
```

This query is NOT fast (matching on either emailAddress or emailAddress2 field):

```
SELECT u.userId
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.isActive=1
AND (u.emailAddress = 'user@domain.com' OR u.emailAddress2 = 'user@domain.com')
```

I have 2 indexes, each on the emailAddress and emailAddress2 field.

**(EDIT) Here is the EXPLAIN output:**

```
id                   1
select_type          SIMPLE
table                u
type                 ref
possible_keys        active,emailAddress,emailAddress2
key                  active
key_len              1
ref                  const
rows                 166808
Extra                Using where
```

Any idea why the 3rd query above is so slow? Suggestions for doing it another way? I need to match on a handful of fields and then get all users EXCEPT ones where their email address is in emailAddress or emailAddress2 (the queries above are simplified for my post).

This is driving me crazy! (and negatively affecting my app's performance).

Thanks

Comment: Oh, just read the part *"the queries above are simplified."* Are these the actual queries or not?

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is slow because first, this query has an `OR` condition which cannot be optimized with a single index (while conditions with only `AND` can) and second, because besides the emails, it has to check the `isActive=1` condition. So it prefers to do a table scan. The other possible path would be to use both email indexes with the [Index Merge Union Access Algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html) but for some reason the optimizer does not choose this plan.

One solution would be to alter the two indexes you have, appending the `isActive` column at the end:

```
ALTER TABLE user 
  DROP INDEX the_name_of_the existing_index,
  DROP INDEX the_name_of_the_other_index,
  ADD INDEX emailAddress_isActive_IX
    (emailAddress, isActive),
  ADD INDEX emailAddress2_isActive_IX
    (emailAddress2, isActive) ;
```

If it still slow (and/or does not do an index merge but prefers the table scan), you could try to rewrite the query with `UNION`:

```
SELECT u.userId
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.isActive=1
AND u.emailAddress = 'user@domain.com'

UNION 

SELECT u.userId
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.isActive=1
AND u.emailAddress2 = 'user@domain.com' ;
```

---

Another option - without necessarily adding/altering indexes - is to nest the query into 2 layers, keeping only the email conditions in the internal layer, essentially forcing MySQL to consider using index-merge with the two available indexes:

```
SELECT userId 
FROM 
    ( SELECT userId, isActive 
      FROM user AS u 
      WHERE emailAddress = 'user@domain.com' 
         OR emailAddress2 = 'user@domain.com'
    ) x 
WHERE isActive=1 ;
```

Comment: If the isActive field were the issue, wouldn't it be slow whether I was checking the emailAddress/emailAddress2 fields or not? I have an index on that as welll. Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Can you edit your question and the EXPLAIN plan (for the slow query)?

Comment: Added some more info. The `OR` is the crucial point, not the `isActive`.

Comment: Doing it with the UNION query method described in your post seems to fix the issue. I would prefer to avoid that, so I'll read up more on the Index Merge Union Access Algorithm and try and figure out how to do that. Is that just essentially a methodology for writing the query in a different way?

Comment: Have you tried adding the suggested indexes?

Comment: Not yet... I'm still doing more testing. The actual queries has other matches on additional columns, so I'm not sure how adding that index would help overall - wouldn't I need multiple indexes for all possible permutations of fields that I'm matching on?

Comment: Can you try running this (before adding any index)? `SELECT userId FROM (SELECT userId, isActive
FROM user AS u WHERE emailAddress = 'user@domain.com' OR emailAddress2 = 'user@domain.com') x WHERE isActive=1;` and its EXPLAIN plan?

Comment: Also, this query is fast... how is this different? (username is also a varchar(255)  field if that matters) -- SELECT u.userId FROM user AS u WHERE active=1
and (username='value' or emailaddress =  'value'). I'm unclear why this would be fast but checking the two email fields would not be fast...

Comment: I can't say anything about what indexes would be useful without seeing the queries. But you are right, indexing needs to consider all your queries, how often they are run, etc.

Comment: The query you just provided is fast...EXPLAIN has a PRIMARY select_type which says "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"; and a DERIVED select_type, with type "index_merge", and in Extra it says `Using union(emailAddress,emailAddress2); Using where; Using index`

Comment: My hunch was right then.

Comment: I like this query format better vs. doing a UNION. So is the gist of it that you should put all of your "OR" conditions in the subquery, and then put the other "AND" conditions outside of that so they get evaluated against the derived table? Can you explain what `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` means in plain English?